# Panning the Raphael surface/Elements in IE and FF is slow and breaking

Tags: raphael, panning

I'm using Raphael plugin and drawing few rectangles and creating few connections between them so that they look like circular/connected graph.

When I start moving the rectangle from its initial position, it will be moving as mouse pointer moves. This is in Chrome browser.

When I test the same functionality in Firefox(20.x.x) and Internet Explorer(8) browsers it is slow and some times the rectangles are breaking while dragging them using the mouse pointer.

Especially it is very slow in Internet Explorer(8) browser, some times the mouse pointer will be at x location and the dragged rectangle will be at some other location.

I do not want the entire graph to be moved at once using Raphael-zpd.js plugin.
I want to know why the functionality is differing in the two browsers.

Is there a way to solve this cross browser issue of Raphael? I tried to find more information on this peculiar behaviour of Raphael but I could not find any.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Firefox and IE8 are not fast browsers for this sort of thing. It's not really Raphael's fault, and there isnt much to be done about it. The best you can do is simplify your graphics by eliminating any filters you have, transparency, gradients, etc. I cant really say without seeing an example.